# Remove substring from fileanme using Powershell command or script

Tags: powershell, substring, file-rename

I know this is very basic and it has been discussed @ multiple places but still I could not find my answer so I am starting a new thread here.

I've started using powershell and I need to write a script to remove substring from filename. 
For example I have below file names -

```
TevarMadamiyan.txt
TevarLetsCelebrate.txt
TevarMMsdfORO.txt
TevarSupper.txt
```

The thing is, I need to remove initial part of filename called "Tever" from all files. How do I do that ?

So far I've tried below method but its not working because new file name becomes empty string -

```
Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace "Tever.*",""}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a typo in `Tever`...anyway the .* will match the whole string which is not what you want. 
Also you want to perform the rename operation on the `basename` rather than the `name`.

The `-whatif` will show you the result without actually performing the rename.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path yourpath -Filter Tevar*.txt | 
  Rename-Item -NewName { ($_.basename -replace 'Tevar') + $_.Extension} -WhatIf
```

Answer (score 0):

.. By using substring.

```
(Get-ChildItem *.txt) | % { Rename-Item $_ (($_.Name).ToString().Substring(5)) }
```